# Android development manifest

Tags: android, manifest

Hi I'm making an android app for the first time and I am stuck I have made a main menu with buttons and I want it to go to another secondary menu for example console games gets clicked and then goes to the console menu view then from there click on the PlayStation button to get to Google maps. The problem is when I get to the console menu the buttons do nothing even when I have the onclicklistener method set to the right button. I have narrowed it down (I think) to the manifest where the problem is but I can't find what is wrong. Here is the whole code .Please Help thanks. :)

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/gf_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:debuggable="true">


    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <!--splash screen-->
    <activity
        android:name=".myMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- main screen -->
    <activity
        android:name=".myMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irou.geekfast.CLEARSCREEN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- console games menu -->
     <activity
        android:name=".consoleGames"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irou.geekfast.CONSOLEGAMES" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <!-- console games menu -->
     <activity
        android:name=".consoleGames"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irou.geekfast.CONSOLEGAMES" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <!-- hardware menu -->
      <activity
        android:name=".mainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irou.geekfast.MAINMENU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />



        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

      <activity
        android:name=".helpBox"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irou.geekfast.HELPBOX" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />



        </intent-filter>


    </activity>

        <!-- Map activity -->
      <activity
        android:name=".consoleMap"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >



        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.irou.geekfast.CONSOLEMAP" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you have provided looks like you are missing Intent Filters

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I fixed it thanks anyway lol I just made a silly mistake I couldn't see :P